# Java, a loop that prints all of the numbers from the min to the max?

Tags: java, loops

All the code works expect the bottom for loop that I'm trying to figure out. Its supposed to print all three numbers that the user inputs from the smallest to largest:

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class CalculateValue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // user input
        int first = Integer.parseInt (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter first number"));
        int second = Integer.parseInt (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter second number"));
        int third = Integer.parseInt (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter third number"));

        // calculate max and min
        int maxValue=first;
        int minValue=first;

        if (second > maxValue) {
            maxValue= second;
        }
        if (second < minValue) {
            minValue = second;  
        }

        if (third > maxValue) {
            maxValue= third;
        }
        if (third < minValue) {
            minValue = third;  
        }
        // display output for largest and smallest numbers
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Largest number: " + maxValue +  " Smallest number: " + minValue);

        //  generate random number between 1 and 100
        int highest = 100;
        int lowest = 1;
        Random randomNum = new Random();
        int display = lowest + randomNum.nextInt(highest);

        // display output for random number
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Random number between 1 and 100:   " + display);

        // for loop that runs through all numbers

        for (int x = minValue; x < maxValue; x++)

            //  output for all numbers
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"All numbers from smallest to largest: " + x );  

    }  
}
```

Comment: Suposing `min = 1` and `max = 5` should it display in a single dialog `All numbers from smalles to largest: 1 2 3 4 5` or display a dialog for each number? That is the last for loop but I'm not sure I understand your problem at all...

Comment: A single dialog would be best.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Arrays.sort()`, which will do a quicksort of your three numbers.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // user input
    int first = Integer.parseInt (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter first number"));
    int second = Integer.parseInt (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter second number"));
    int third = Integer.parseInt (JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter third number"));

    int[] numbers = new int[] { first, second, third};
    Arrays.sort(numbers);

    // display output for largest and smallest numbers
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Largest number: " + numbers[2] +  " Smallest number: " + numbers[0]);

    //  generate random number between 1 and 100
    int highest = 100;
    int lowest = 1;
    Random randomNum = new Random();
    int display = lowest + randomNum.nextInt(highest);

    // display output for random number
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Random number between 1 and 100:   " + display);

    //  output for all numbers
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"All numbers from smallest to largest: " + numbers[0] + " ," + numbers[1] + ", " + numbers[2] );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I recommend you to add curly braces to all your loops, otherwise you might confuse yourself.

That said, to create a single dialog with all the values between min and max, you should create a `StringBuilder` that stores them all and concatenate it to your text:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int x = minValue; x < maxValue; x++) {
    sb.append(x);
    sb.append(", "); //Add a comma and space or just a space or the char you want to separate each entry
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"All numbers from smallest to largest: " + sb.toString());  //This will concatenate
```

That should give you all the values in a single dialog.

Or if you want a single dialog with all 3 values displayed you could use the above with the following:

```
JPanel pane = new JPanel();
pane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

pane.add(new JLabel(" Largest number: " + maxValue));
pane.add(new JLabel(" Smallest number: " + minValue));
pane.add(new JLabel("Random number between 1 and 100:   " + display));
pane.add(new JLabel("All numbers from smallest to largest: " + sb.toString());

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, pane);
```

And it will display all the values in a single `JDialog` each of them in a new row.